# Is there a way to delegate full Ansible playbooks (and not just tasks) to another host?

Tags: ansible, delegation

Is there any way to delegate complete playbooks to another host ? It seems, that the delegate_to paradigm only applies to tasks. 
Here is the specific scenario I am trying to solve: 
Host A (happens to be an AWX /Tower host) is orchestrating the "big picture"
Host B is intended to run the nitty-gritty stuff. In fact ,host B shall perform a full blown ceph installation which requires a lot more pre-req's than host A can provide. The ceph installer is shipped as one big piece of playbook "site.yml" that runs fine on host B, but not on host A.

Any ideas how to solve this ?

I would imagine people run into a similar situation if e.g. the final targets are sitting behind a firewall that does not nat-out every target to the Ansible host. Here you would also like to delegate the complete playbook to a "Jump" host behind the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your exact requirement. You seem to be describing a need for a hierarchy of 'control nodes' (i.e. the host that in a basic environment would run `ansible-playbook`). I am not aware of an Ansible native method of achieving this, however I am not massively familiar with Tower, so perhaps someone who is will provide more detail.

Your specific example however, describes the case of remote nodes to be managed, being located behind a jump box. Ansible does natively support that case, so if your requirement is simply that you need to access your nodes via a jump box, and thus don't specifically need the jump box to act as a control node, that is already covered.

Check out "[How do I configure a jump host to access servers that I have no direct access to?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html)" in the FAQ. There are also several blog posts on the subject of configuring this:

https://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/12/24/running-ansible-through-ssh-bastion-host/
https://selivan.github.io/2018/01/29/ansible-ssh-bastion-host.html[enter link description here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response. The gatewayd option via ansible_host=1.2.3.4 might work. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

We have gotton around the issue of requiring a dedicated server to dispatch the playbooks to by making use of virtualenv's in Ansible Tower. 
This is the more elegant solution anyway, so this thread can be closed.